# How to prove sinc function series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

I am not sure how to prove this series for the sinc function:
$$\text{sinc}(x)=2\cos\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\sum_{n = 0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{2 n}}{2^{2 n + 1}(2 n + 1)!}.$$
Is there an elementary proof? Any ideas?

Comment: Hint: $$\frac{x^{2n}}{2^{2n+1}} = \frac{1}{x} \left(\frac{x}{2}\right)^{2n+1}$$

Comment: Simple proof: Note $\frac{\sin(x)}{2x\cos(x/2)} = \frac{\sin(x/2)}{x}$ (comes from $\sin(2x)$ identity and rearrangement) and expand the RHS in a power series. This is not research level, and belongs on MSE instead

Comment: The RHS is $2x^{-1}\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)$.

Comment: The sum is Taylor series expansion of sin half angle divided by x. Then combine with sin double angle formula.

Answer (score 0):

Start with 
$$\sin(x)=2\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)$$
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac2x\cos(x/2)\sin(x/2)$$
Then use $$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}x^{2n+1}$$
To get
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac2x\cos\frac{x}2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\left(\frac{x}2\right)^{2n+1}$$
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\frac2x\cos\frac{x}2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n+1}}{2^{2n+1}(2n+1)!}$$
$$\operatorname{sinc}(x)=\cos\frac{x}2\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{2^{2n}(2n+1)!}$$
QED